# This location could not be displayed on Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: disk

I've formatted my computer, I saved my files in this disk, after install Ubuntu I can't access the disk.

[image]

when I try to access this disk, it says

```
This location could not be displayed you do not have the permission to view the content
```

[image]

How to open the disk?

Comment: If you type 'mount' in a terminal when the disk is plugged in, what is the output?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't have permissions to see a drive, you can set permissions as root in the terminal:
(Change "user" with your Linux user)

```
# chown -R user:user /media
# chmod -R 775 /media
```

EDIT: Although I was happy to help you and solve the problem, I must also say that this could also be a security breach as long as everyone else in the computer can see and run every media file inside the `/media` tree path.

If you have more users, or simple want to keep your files away from other's eyes, check the meaning of the permissions and set them accordingly.

For example: `chmod -R 750` to be allowed to do everything to your files; everyone else in your user group, can watch and run; and the rest, well, could not even watch if there is any folder, even less what stuff there is inside them (again, unless you give them permissions).

Comment: thank you, you saved my life! or at least, you saved me from thinking my life was over