# Cannot access windows 10 C drive on Ubuntu

Tags: 18.04

I've got some "issues" with Windows 10 and I've installed Ubuntu on a separate drive and I want to access my C: drive but it doesn't let me (It says "This location could not be displayed").
I cannot access Windows 10 to completely shut it down to then be able to access them.
All I want to do is copy some files from Program Files x86.

Edit: All other drives work, except for the windows one (C:)

Comment: Is it something like this [This location could not be displayed on Ubuntu 16.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/858793/this-location-could-not-be-displayed-on-ubuntu-16-10)?

Comment: @CuBe If you don't completely shut down Windows 10 before you open Ubuntu, C: is locked. Please make sure you chose Shut Down and not Hibernate or Restart in Windows before you restart for Ubuntu.

Comment: Default for Win 10 is to have fast boot turned on, so windows hibernates instead of turning completely off when using shut down option.

Comment: Reread the question, seems like you are saying that your windows is not bootable.  Think your best bet in that case is to try to use windows tools/repair disk to try to copy what you want.

Comment: @crip659 Yeah, I know I have to completely shut down windows. I have tried Windows' disk repair but it seems that it freezes. I would try to keep it running for more than 7 hours. (it didn't finish after 6-7 hours)

Comment: Would try googling repair window file system/disk.  Might find something better than what windows has on disk, or a way to copy your data.